# ROS Answers SE migration: Fuerte and FCL

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, fcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running on Fuerte (Groovy is not an option) and I would like to use FCL (Flexible Collision Library). I've installed the ros-fuerte-fcl package with apt-get, but cannot find any information on how to actually use it. Can someone point me in the right direction?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62332/fuerte-and-fcl/) by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 452 on 2013-05-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) on 2013-05-07**:
I've also tried the standalone FCL package, and it builds fine, and it runs the included test fine, but there doesn't seem to be any examples or documentation to it, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I was getting started using FCL, I found these references helpful:

- the original [FCL Paper](http://gamma.cs.unc.edu/FCL/fcl.pdf) documents many of the core concepts
- the [API Documentation](http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/fcl/html/) on the ROS wiki.  Especially under the [fcl Namespace](http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/fcl/html/namespacefcl.html), as many FCL capabilities are exposed as bare functions in the root `fcl` namespace.
- the various `test_*.cpp` unit-test programs, which can be reviewed [here](http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/fcl/html/files.html)

From the ROS side, you'll need to make sure `fcl` is listed as a dependency in your package's `manifest.xml`.  Also, the `CMakeLists.txt` should include a `target_link_libraries(my_exe fcl)` line to link the library to your executable.  As shown in the FCL test programs, you'll need to explicitly link individual header files for the specific FCL modules you want to use: `#include "fcl/collision_node.h"`, etc.

To start, I'd try creating a small test program.  You could construct a few primitives (spheres or cubes) of known geometry, at known distances, and call the FCL methods to check for collisions or distances.  This is essentially what is done in the FCL unit-test programs.  This test program will allow you to verify that you have your ROS environment set correctly (dependencies, includes, linking, etc.) and at least a basic working implementation of FCL.  From there, you can expand the FCL portion to more directly implement what you're trying to do for your application.

Mostly, I had to stumble my way through getting started.  But once I had some working code, the library was fairly easy to use and very powerful!  We're doing distance checks between large meshes at a very acceptable rate.  Other than the initial setup headaches, I've been very pleased.

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) on 2013-05-07**:
Great information, thanks!